# RecipeCloudfoundry Chef Compile Error in cloudfoundry/vcap/dev_setup/cookbooks/cloud_controller/attributes/default.rb

Tags: 12.04

I've just installed Cloudfoundry Server PaaS on Ubuntu 11.10 [following this step-by-step guide](http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2011/08/howto-install-cloudfoundry-server-paas.html). How do I install the same on Ubuntu 12.04?

I have tried to install cloudfoundry v2 on Ubuntu 12.04 using vagrant, but that version is not perfectly installed yet. Many service like mysql, redis etc not included yet.

Then I trid to install cloudfoundry with chef, but i got error like bellow :

```
Recipe Compile Error in /home/user1/cloudfoundry/vcap/dev_setup/cookbooks/cloud_controller/attributes/default.rb
```

Bellow full log message :

```
$ bash < <(curl -s -k -B https://raw.github.com/cloudfoundry/vcap/master/dev_setup/bin/vcap_dev_setup)

Installing wget...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
... 
...

[2013-08-27T14:31:42+00:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for paas.dc31001b77fa4c5a8aa4b0724d0fd095.openpaas.2767201159.asiaeast.internal.cloudapp.net
[2013-08-27T14:31:42+00:00] INFO: Running start handlers
[2013-08-27T14:31:42+00:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.
Compiling Cookbooks...

================================================================================
Recipe Compile Error in /home/user1/cloudfoundry/vcap/dev_setup/cookbooks/cloud_controller/attributes/default.rb
================================================================================


NoMethodError
-------------
Undefined node attribute or method `include_recipe' on `node'


Cookbook Trace:
---------------
  /home/user1/cloudfoundry/vcap/dev_setup/cookbooks/cloud_controller/attributes/default.rb:1:in `from_file'


Relevant File Content:
----------------------
/home/user1/cloudfoundry/vcap/dev_setup/cookbooks/cloud_controller/attributes/default.rb:

  1>> include_recipe "deployment"
  2:  include_attribute "postgresql"
  3:  include_attribute "redis"
  4:  include_attributes "uaa"
  5:  include_attributes "service_lifecycle"
  6:  
  7:  default[:deployment][:welcome] = "VMware's Cloud Application Platform"
  8:  
  9:  default[:cloud_controller][:config_file] = "cloud_controller.yml"
 10:  default[:cloud_controller][:service_api_uri] = "http://api.#{node[:deployment][:domain]}"



[2013-08-27T14:31:42+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2013-08-27T14:31:42+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2013-08-27T14:31:42+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated
[2013-08-27T14:31:42+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
user1@paas:~$ uname -a
Linux paas 3.2.0-39-virtual #62-Ubuntu SMP Thu Feb 28 00:48:27 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
user1@paas:~$ nano /home/user1/cloudfoundry/vcap/dev_setup/cookbooks/cloud_controller/attributes/default.rb
```